# PHP: str_replace how replace some string with one variable number?

Tags: php, string, replace

I am trying to learning something about PHP, and I don't know how to do it, something like this:

I have a string:

```
$text = 'This is your post number [postnumb], This is [postnumb], And this is your post number [postnumb].';
```

And with PHP I want to change the string `[postnumb]` to the number of post:

```
$textchanged = 'This is your post number 1, This is your post number 2, This is your post number 3.';
```

Any help for me? Thanks.

Comment: you want the same string `[postnumb]` to equal 3 different values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace), you can use the 4th argument to limit the replacement to the first occurrence. Combine this with a loop that will run until there are no occurrences remaining, and you can achieve what you're after:

```
$text = 'This is your post number [postnumb], This is [postnumb], And this is your post number [postnumb].';

$i = 0;
while(true)
{
    $prev = $text;
    $text = preg_replace('/\[postnumb\]/', ++$i, $text, 1);

    if($prev === $text)
    {
        // There were no changes, exit the loop.
        break;
    }
}

echo $text; // This is your post number 1, This is 2, And this is your post number 3.
```

Comment: Just more one question:
/\[postnumb\]/
What represents /\ , \ and / ?

Thanks.

Comment: @user3242852 `preg_replace` accepts a regex pattern, not a string. Regex patterns need a delimiter of your choice on either side of the expression, and special characters like `[]{}?.` need to be escaped with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("[postnumb]", 1, $text);
```

You can't set different numbers for `[postnumb]` using `str_replace()` (unless you do it manually for substrings).

`preg_replace()` should help you for that case, or using different **tags** for different numbers (like `[postnumb2]` and `[postnumb]`).